# How can I animate a log stream in javascript/css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, css-animations

I have a stream of events in my browser.  I want to animate them as a list - when a new event comes, the other items smoothly slide down one item, and the new one fades in at the top of the list.

I'd prefer to use a lightweight animation engine like transit.js or velocity.js

I have tried `translateY: '1em'` but rather than moving all items down 1 line it seems to move them down the first time, and successive calls keep it there.

example code

```
<ul id="container">
  <li>blah</li>
  <li>yoyo</li>
</ul>
```

and js

```
$("#container").children().velocity({ 
   translateY: "1em"
 }, 1000);

$("#container").prepend("<li>yar</li>");

$("#container").children().velocity({ 
   translateY: "1em"
 }, 1000);

$("#container").prepend("<li>yar</li>");
```

on codepen: http://codepen.io/ankopainting/pen/KNwYxJ

Comment: Append the new item and call `slideDown()`, maybe? Hard to help you without you showing us any of your existing code

Comment: My existing code doesn't work! I'm looking for a technique on how it can be done.  I've tried many things.  And no, appending the item and calling slideDown() doesn't work - that would display an element with a sliding motion, not translate them all and fade in a new one.

Comment: Thanks for adding a sample. For reference, we need to see your broken code so that we can see the context you're working in. I added an answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you need you can prepend the new item and then call `slideDown()`, like this:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('<li>foo</li>').addClass('added-item').prependTo('#container').slideDown();
});
```

```css
.added-item {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="container">
  <li>blah</li>
  <li>yoyo</li>
</ul>

<button>Add item</button>
```

Comment: This just makes the new element slide in rather than making the items slide down and fading in the new element.